# C# cut rectangle blocks from image

Tags: c#, image-processing, screenshot

I develop a screen sharing app and i would like to make it as efficient as posibble so im trying to send only the differences between the screen shots.
So, suppose we have this image for example:its a 32bpprgba image with transpert parts around.
 [image]

I would like to store each one of the blocks here as a rectangle in a List and get them bounds. It may sounds very complex but actually it just requires a little logic.
This is my code so far:

```
    private unsafe List<Rectangle> CodeImage(Bitmap bmp)
    {

        List<Rectangle> rec = new List<Rectangle>();
        Bitmap bmpRes = new Bitmap(bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
        BitmapData bmData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);
        IntPtr scan0 = bmData.Scan0;
        int stride = bmData.Stride;
        int nWidth = bmp.Width;
        int nHeight = bmp.Height;
        int minX = int.MaxValue; ;
        int minY = int.MaxValue;
        int maxX = 0;
        bool found = false;


        for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
        {
            byte* p = (byte*)scan0.ToPointer();
            p += y * stride;


            for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
            {

                if (p[3] != 0)  //Check if pixel is not transparent;
                {

                    found = true;
                    if (x < minX)
                        minX = x;
                    if (x > maxX)
                        maxX = x;
                    if (y < minY)
                        minY = y;

                }

                else
                {

                    if (found)
                    {

                        int height = getBlockHeight(stride, scan0, maxX, minY);
                        found = false;
                        Rectangle temp = new Rectangle(minX, minY, maxX - minX, height);
                        rec.Add(temp);
                        y += minY;
                        break;

                    }
                }
                p += 4;//add to the pointer 4 bytes;
            }
        }

        return rec;
    }
```

as you see im trying to scan the image using the height and width, and when i found a pixel i send it to `GetBlockHeight` function to get it's height:

```
  public unsafe int getBlockHeight(int stride, IntPtr scan, int x, int y1)
    {

        int height = 0; ;
        for (int y = y1; y < 1080; y++)
        {
            byte* p = (byte*)scan.ToPointer();
            p += (y * stride) + (x * 4); 

            if (p[3] != 0)  //Check if pixel is not transparent;
            {

                height++;
            }

        }
        return height;
    }
```

But im just not getting the result... i think there's somthing with the logic here... can anyone light my eyes?  i know it requires a bit time and  thinking but i would very very appreciate anyone who could help a little.

Comment: It seems that `maxX` will always be `int.MaxValue`. You would also need to reset it after matching a block. Furthermore what do you want to support in the long run? Multiple rectangles on the same vertical position? Non-rectangular areas?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis only rectangular areas at this moment. about the `maxX ` yeah you were right.. changed it but it still not really close... and yep, i guess there will be multiple rectangle on the same line.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis what do you mean by reset it? break the loop and initiate the values? i would very appreciate if you can explain a little more or show a simple example. thanks.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis still there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your current algorithm, after successfully matching a rectangle, you increase `y` with its height and `break` out of the inner loop. This means you can only detect data for one rectangle per horizontal line.

If I were you I'd think about the following things, before jumping back into the code:

- Save the complete image as a PNG file, and look at its size. Is further processing really required?
- Are these rectangles accurate? Will there be scenario's in which you would be constantly sending the contents of the entire screen anyway?
- If you're developing for Windows, you might be able to hook into the procedure that invalidates areas on the screen, in which case you wouldn't have to determine these rectangles yourself. I don't know about other OSes

Also I personally wouldn't try to solve the rectangle-detection algorithm in a "nesty" `for`-loop, but go with something like this:

```
public void FindRectangles(Bitmap bitmap, Rectangle searchArea, List<Rectangle> results)
{
    // Find the first non-transparent pixel within the search area. 
    // Ensure that it is the pixel with the lowest y-value possible
    Point p;
    if (!TryFindFirstNonTransparent(bitmap, searchArea, out p))
    {
        // No non-transparent pixels in this area
        return;
    }

    // Find its rectangle within the area
    Rectangle r = GetRectangle(bitmap, p, searchArea);
    results.Add(r);

    // No need to search above the rectangle we just found
    Rectangle left = new Rectangle(searchArea.Left, r.Top, r.Left - searchArea.Left, searchArea.Bottom - r.Top);
    Rectangle right = new Rectangle(r.Right, r.Top, searchArea.Right - r.Right, searchArea.Bottom - r.Top);
    Rectangle bottom = new Rectangle(r.Left, r.Bottom, r.Width, searchArea.Bottom - r.Bottom);

    FindRectangles(bitmap, left, results);
    FindRectangles(bitmap, right, results);
    FindRectangles(bitmap, bottom, results);
}

public Rectangle GetRectangle(Bitmap bitmap, Point p, Rectangle searchArea)
{
    int right = searchArea.Right;
    for (int x = p.X; x < searchArea.Right; x++)
    {
        if (IsTransparent(x, p.Y))
        {
            right = x - 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    int bottom = searchArea.Bottom;
    for (int y = p.Y; y < searchArea.Bottom; y++)
    {
        if (IsTransparent(p.X, y))
        {
            bottom = y - 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    return new Rectangle(p.X, p.Y, right - p.X, bottom - p.Y);
}
```

This approach, when fully implemented, should give you a list of rectangles (although it will occasionally split a rectangle in two).

(Of course instead of providing the `bitmap`, you'd pass the pointer to the pixel data with some metadata instead)

Comment: thanks you very much!  About the processing it's do required because the image above was just an example and in my program I'm going to process screen shots which in png format can get up to 1mb+!

Comment: and few questions -what's actually the get rectangle method?

Comment: I don't know about the full screen sending -but I don't think I would send a full size screen shot. ..only the differences . By the way, is requresion really more efficient in this case?  Will I be able to feel the code performance improvement?

Comment: The GetRectangle should determine the width and height of the rectangle, given the location of its top-left pixel. Sorry I should have mentioned that.

Comment: I didn't really focus on performance (I don't think it will be much faster/slower than your loops), but wanted to show a different approach which I find easier to follow.

Comment: okay but how am I supposed to implement the 'GetRectangle' method?

Comment: About sending the screenshot - I meant sending the bitmap that you currently use as input, the one with many transparent pixels. PNG should be able to compress that pretty good.

Comment: yeah I also tried it. .. but I want to minimize the network traffic as much as possible. What about the GetRectangle?  Should I insert my code that I posted there?

Comment: thanks man I'm not home right now I'll try this later! Your awesome

Comment: You already tried compressing the image-with-transparency - is its size drastically more than the size of the individual rectangle images combined? Is the size difference worth the time of the per-pixel comparison?

Comment: this it a question I always asked myself. .and seems like yes. .If I send each block at least there is a faster update of the screen on the serve side...